# escape character mysql import

Tags: escaping, mysql, mysqlimport

Recently I needed to migrate my website and all of its contents. I backed everything up and manually unpacked everything on the new hosting. A very tedious process, to say the least.

However, after the move I discovered that the the Wordpress database was borked and I just figured out the problem.

The Unicode text character `’` (u8217) is used in some text portions of the site. For whatever unknown reason, this character is causing the inserts to terminate at that character. I know this because the text portions before that character successfully get inserted, and everything else is omitted. (I've edited this post because in my original post I thought it was the culprit was the `'` apostrophe character but it is the unicode character `’`)

The command I used to backup is:

```
mysqldump --no-create-db --add-drop-table --all-databases -u [username] –p[password] -h [host] > backup.sql
```

The command I'm using to import is:

```
mysql -u [username] -p[password] -h [host] < backup.sql
```

Comment: You don't need to escape anything - all required characters are escaped automatically. Instead you have to put a little more effort in investigating what certainly "broke". Did you have any error messages while importing? If not - all the ' characters got escaped properly and your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Good point, sorry I didn't explain it more. After import, the row with `Today's` has the rest of the text cut off. So, the assumption was that the SQL insert is ending there. But no, no error messages (unless they're being logged somewhere that I don't know of).

Comment: How do you know that "the rest is cut off"? Where do you see it? In your application? How could you tell that it's mysql backup, not your application to blame? Why not to see **right in the dump file**?

Comment: 1) The website that pertains to the wordpress database being imported and 2) the row after import.

Comment: Actually, I did look at it further and I realized the character that is causing the trouble is not a `'` but actually it is a `’` character.

Comment: a `’` character does have no special meaning in mysql and cannot interfere with the query at all

Comment: Ok well I can tell that the application is not to blame because I am looking at the database row that was inserted and it does not contain the `’` character or any text after that. My suspicion is that it is an encoding issue.

Comment: The backup is not to blame, the application is not to blame. It's the import that is messing up. Does the `mysql` command produce an error log I can view?

Comment: it can produce if told so. but by default errors are shown right in place. Did you see any?

Comment: I re-ran the `mysql` after mass refractoring `’` to `'`, and it produced an error: `ERROR at line 273: Unknown command '\"'.` So now I'm really confused.

Comment: Do not interfere with dump manually. Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Well, the import with the same script worked on a local wamp configuration. So, something is screwy with my host's version of MySQL I'm assuming.

Comment: A quick java test shows that this is unicode character 8217 (the int value of the char '’'. A quick google search yielded promising results.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is still a mystery to me because the `mysql` SSH command did not yeild any errors, I at the very least was able to fix the problem by copy/pasting the dump file's contents into phpMyAdmin's sql window and executing it. The inserts went through just fine so the problem appears to be within the `mysql` command solely.

A google search did not yeild any promising leads into the problem, so hopefully this thread will be useful to someone else. Thank you very much to "@Your Common Sense" for asking crucial questions to show me the problem was not what I thought it was originally.